# Delete record from grid view after user check/tick the record in c#

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox, delete-row

I need you all help on pulling data from a table based on lot num, and then displayed it into grid view.
Then for the grid view, there are check box on each records for user to check and click on the delete button.
Once delete the record will be deleted.
Can anyone of you show me any reference or example?

Seriously need help. Thanks.

Comment: is it WPF based application. I am not clear if you asking to remove the entries from grid and from source once user click delete button ?

Comment: You need to use your searching skills to find refrence online. Try out some solution and comeback with any problem faced.

Comment: @Rahul, it is c# language. Yes, delete from source (database).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me from aspsnippets.com,

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx

Comment: Thanks @shubham. Your resource is useful to me. Can you help me one more thing? My scenario is that, for one lot num, it will return many records, say lot A will return price 1, 2, 3, and I just want to delete price 3, how to do that? How to write a query that recognise a record/column price say price 3 which is the one that i want to delete. If this is workable, then i can write a query : delete from table where lotnum = A and price = 3. Do you still have references for me? Really need help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you want to delete from your source data(database table) or just not show in gridview?

Comment: want to delete from source data, and also from gridview, as gridview is select statement from the table.

Comment: so why not delete it from source? I mean, what is the condition you would like to add before deleting some row?

Comment: this is a page for user to delete themselves as we are supporting their request always (just to delete records).

Answer (score 0):

refer GridView below example, Main things to see 
1. OnRowDeletingEvent 
2. Checkbox and button in ItemTemplate

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" **OnRowDeleting="GVID_RowDeleting"** >
<column>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Checkbox ID="CHKID" runat="server" Text=**'<%#Eval("IDColumnName") %>'** />
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" **CommandName="Delete"** />
</column>
```

C# code behind:

```
    protected void GV_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
        Button btnDelete = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");
        CheckBox CHKID= (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CHKID");

     if(CHKID.Checked == true)
     {
       if(CHKID.Text !="")
       {
         int id = Convert.ToInt32(CHKID.Text);
         //Pass this ID to DB and Delete record.
       }
     }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Reply to this : "is this code correct? – user548682 3 hours ago"  `Text='<%#Eval("Lotnum") %>'` Please add Lot Number in Check box column. and Getdata of price as we are getting using Find Control ... then ur query will work

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Button btnDelete = (Button)gvResult.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");
            CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)gvResult.Row.FindControl("chkBox");
            if (chkBox.Checked == true)
            {
                if (chkBox.Text != "")
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(chkBox.Text);
                    //Pass this ID to DB and Delete record.
                    string SQL = string.Format(@"DELETE FROM RF_HANDLING WHERE LOTNUM = '{0}' AND PRICE = '{1}'", LotName, PRICE);
                }
            }
        }
```